# Paypal integration to serve multiple sellers in one go for a shopping site

Tags: e-commerce, paypal, payment-gateway, shopping-cart

We are in a process of making a shopping site. Here, the buyer can select the items of their choice and put them in shopping cart. These items can be from different sellers. Now, when the buyer makes the payment we want that the amount should be automatically deposited in each sellers account as per his product price.

Please suggest, how this can be achieved using paypal?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps via an intermediary account?

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid that you can not do that for the moment.

this will be possible soon with the new API (Split Payment or parallel payment)
You will find more information on x.com

Cheers